# What is the XOP prefix in an instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code, instructions, amd-processor

I've been reading through some source code recently and this caught my eye particularly:

```
/**
 * Decodes the `XOP`-prefix.
 *
 * @param   context     A pointer to the `ZydisDecoderContext` struct.
 * @param   instruction A pointer to the `ZydisDecodedInstruction` struct.
 * @param   data        The `XOP` bytes.
 *
 * @return  A zyan status code.
 */
static ZyanStatus ZydisDecodeXOP(ZydisDecoderContext* context,
    ZydisDecodedInstruction* instruction, const ZyanU8 data[3])
{
    ZYAN_ASSERT(instruction);
    ZYAN_ASSERT(data[0] == 0x8F);
    ZYAN_ASSERT(((data[1] >> 0) & 0x1F) >= 8);
    ZYAN_ASSERT(instruction->raw.xop.offset == instruction->length - 3);

    instruction->attributes |= ZYDIS_ATTRIB_HAS_XOP;
    instruction->raw.xop.R       = (data[1] >> 7) & 0x01;
    instruction->raw.xop.X       = (data[1] >> 6) & 0x01;
    instruction->raw.xop.B       = (data[1] >> 5) & 0x01;
    instruction->raw.xop.m_mmmm  = (data[1] >> 0) & 0x1F;

    if ((instruction->raw.xop.m_mmmm < 0x08) || (instruction->raw.xop.m_mmmm > 0x0A))
    {
        // Invalid according to the AMD documentation
        return ZYDIS_STATUS_INVALID_MAP;
    }

    instruction->raw.xop.W    = (data[2] >> 7) & 0x01;
    instruction->raw.xop.vvvv = (data[2] >> 3) & 0x0F;
    instruction->raw.xop.L    = (data[2] >> 2) & 0x01;
    instruction->raw.xop.pp   = (data[2] >> 0) & 0x03;

    // Update internal fields
    context->cache.W = instruction->raw.xop.W;
    context->cache.R = 0x01 & ~instruction->raw.xop.R;
    context->cache.X = 0x01 & ~instruction->raw.xop.X;
    context->cache.B = 0x01 & ~instruction->raw.xop.B;
    context->cache.L = instruction->raw.xop.L;
    context->cache.LL = instruction->raw.xop.L;
    context->cache.v_vvvv = (0x0F & ~instruction->raw.xop.vvvv);

    return ZYAN_STATUS_SUCCESS;
}
```

The code doesn't actually matter here: all I am wondering is what the "XOP" prefix is. It's not mentioned anywhere in the Intel or AMD documentation, and I found little to no information.

Anyone knows what is it? Is it an AMD-Instruction only prefix? If it is, what is it's Intel counterpart?

Comment: Maybe this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOP_instruction_set

Comment: you can find lots of answers by googling for "xop prefix x86": https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#VEX.2FXOP_opcodes

Comment: XOP is an AMD-only prefix for AMD-specific SIMD instructions available in Bulldozer/Piledriver/Steamroller/Excavator chips.  The first byte is `8F` followed by two other bytes and then an opcode.  Refer to the AMD manuals for details.

Comment: The Intel counterpart is the quite similar VEX prefix, used for AVX and some BMI instructions, among other things.

Comment: [*In May 2009, AMD announced a revision of the proposed SSE5 instruction set to make it compatible with the AVX instruction set and the VEX coding scheme. The revised SSE5 is called XOP.*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix#History)